# Are the negations of these statements correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

If today is New Year's Eve, then tomorrow is January.

Negation: Today is New Year's Eve and tomorrow is not January.

If *y* is non negative, then *y* is positive or *y* is 0.

Negation: Y is not a non negative and both y is not positive and y is not 0.

If *n* is divisible by 6, then *n* is divisible by 2 and *n* is divisible by 3.

Negation:

N is divisible by 6 and either n is not divisible by 2 or n is not divisible by 3.

Comment: The middle one is wrong. The negation of "if $x$ then $y$" is, as you correctly got in the first and third, "$x$ and not $y$."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The middle one is wrong. The negation of "if $x$ then $y$" is, as you correctly got in the first and third, "$x$ and not $y$."